# Equation of Continuity when a pipe is divided into many smaller pipes

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow

My question is regarding the application of equation of continuity in a particular case when a pipe is divided into many smaller pipes.

The equation of continuity makes use of the fact that mass of water passing into the pipe is equal to the mass of water passing out of the pipe.

Let the mass of water flowing in through a pipe of radius $R$, per second be $M$, let the pipe be divided into smaller pipes  of radii $r$. So the mass of water passing out through a smaller pipe is M/n where n is no. of smaller pipes.

As $M$ is not equal to $\frac{M}{n}$(apart from a particular case when $n=M$), is the equation of continuity still valid between the larger pipe and one of the smaller pipes?

Comment: Yes the continuity equation applies- unless there is a leak somewhere.

Comment: I know that but I am verifying how it's applied in the above case

Comment: What makes your case different? Does the equation of continuity apply for 1 pipe splitting into 2? into 3? into 4? ... at what point does it not apply? The total mass flow is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way in which you can write the continuity equation between two points on a pipe is
$$\rho_1 A_1 v_1 = \rho_2 A_2 v_2$$
where $\rho$ is density, $A$ is the cross-sectional area, and $v$ is speed (for simple enough flow). This is essentially saying that the mass flow rate $Q=\rho A v$ is constant. Water is incompressible, so we'll assume that $\rho$ is constant.

Say you have a big pipe, and that somehow the flow is split equally between 100 smaller pipes. This means that the mass flow rate in the small pipes will be $1/100$ of the mass flow rate in the big pipe:
$$Q_{small} = \frac{Q_{big}}{100}$$
This is the equation of continuity between the small pipe and the big pipe. So if point $1$ is in the big pipe and point $2$ is in the small pipe, now you write (assuming $\rho$ constant):
$$\frac{A_1 v_1}{100} =A_2 v_2$$
Of course if the two points you're comparing are both in the big pipe or both in the small pipe, you would use the usual equation at the top.